# What will happen if I make a parisian flan with all 1% milk instead of whole milk and heavy cream?

Tags: baking, dessert, french-cuisine

All the recipes I've seen for parisian flans use a combination of whole milk and heavy cream. What will happen if I only use 1% milk? Will it affect just the taste and a little bit of texture or will the whole thing just not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work. Egg custard can be made with basically any liquid, the fat in the dairy is just for taste. Go ahead and make it, it will still be a flan.

Note that the chemistry of custards is somewhat finicky, and certain ingredients, including the fat, increase your leeway. When you make it with your low-fat milk, you should be extra careful to not overcook it.

Comment: Thank you very much! What will happen if I overcook it and by overcook, do you mean in the oven or on the stovetop?

Comment: Flans are made in the oven. On stovetop, you have to make stirred custards. If you overcook it slightly, you will get wormholes through it and liquid will seep out. If you overcook it a lot, it will be grainy, and may taste a bit like scrambled eggs.